# Почему открывается три окна вместо одного?

Tags: javascript

Сегодня начал Javascript изучать и столкнулся сразу с одной проблемой. Есть на странице 3 кнопки, после клика по одной из них, должно появлятся окно с текстом, причем для каждой кнопки, текст отдельный. Вот мой код, но он почему-то не пашет. Я нажимаю на кнопку (любую) и мне открывается одно за другим 3 окошка, вместо 1-го.
Форма и кнопки:

```
<form method="post" target="_blank" enctype="text/plain" name="acc">
<p align="center">
    input  onclick="Hellid('a')"type="button" value="Username" name="usn" /></br></br>
    input  onclick="Hellid('b')"type="button" value="Password" name="pas" /></br></br>
    input  onclick="Hellid('c')"type="button" value="E-mail" name="eml" />
</p>
<form>
```

Функция:

```
function Hellid() {
    var a = document.acc.usn.value;
    var b = document.acc.pas.value;
    var c = document.acc.eml.value;

    if (onclick = "a") {
        alert("Loading");
    }
    if (onclick = "b") {
        alert("All Ready");
    }
    if (onclick = "c") {
        alert("Yep");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пропишите примерно так:

```
function Hellid (hellishId) {
    ...
    if (hellishId == "a") { alert ("Loading");}
    else if (hellishId == "b") { alert ("All Ready");}
    else if (hellishId == "c") { alert ("Yep");}
}
```

Так как вы только начинаете изучать синтаксис языка, обратите внимание на == в сравнении.

Comment: а в Html что нужно тогда изменить, а то все равно не работает.

Comment: А как должно работать?

Answer (score 3):

Я не большой спец в JS, но кое-что понимаю в HTML. А разве тэг не должен начинаться с "<"? Не?

```
<input  onclick="Hellid('c')"type="button" value="E-mail" name="eml" />
```